# Dots between a long list of elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ideally I'd like to solve this problem with pure CSS, but I'd imagine this likely needs JS to be solved

I have a long unordered list, with bullets between them, which looks like this:
[image]

I have styled it like this:

```
.names li:not(:last-child):after {
    font-weight: lighter;
    content: "\25CF";
    color: #C70039;
}

.names ul li { display: inline; white-space: pre; }
.names ul li:last-child:after { content: ""; }

.names {
    margin-right: 15%;
    margin-left: 15%;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: justify;
    display: inline-block;
}

.names li {
    display: inline;
}
```

How can I stop the bullets appearing at the edge like that? Keeping in mind it needs to be responsive

Comment: left edge, right edge or both? (also share your HTML)

Comment: @TemaniAfif both

Comment: add your html code to make it easy for us and we don't have to write manually a random code to test

Comment: the list is taken from a csv which is served via a backend API call and then it's just a set of UL and LIs @TemaniAfif

Comment: if it's a *just* ul/li then you can easily do a copy/paste inside the question to have a full code. We don't need the image but we need the code that we can run

Answer (score 1):

Remove the padding from the `<ul>`, and set the `overflow` to `hidden`. Use `::before` on all list items to display the red dot, and also set a fixed width of `1em` to the `::before`. Now use `position: relative` and `left: -1em` on the `<li>` items to hide the red dot on the left side.

```css
.names li::before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  font-weight: lighter;
  content: "\25CF";
  color: #C70039;
}

.names ul {
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.names ul li {
  position: relative;
  left: -1em;
  display: inline;
  white-space: pre;
}

.names {
  margin-right: 15%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: justify;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="names">
  <ul>
    <li>Calvin Manning</li>
    <li>Zachariah Little</li>
    <li>Stephanie Lowery</li>
    <li>Tori Lynn</li>
    <li>Lucas Hogan</li>
    <li>Tristian Thornton</li>
    <li>Madison Preston</li>
    <li>Azul Robertson</li>
    <li>Ulises Pruitt</li>
    <li>Jayleen Roth</li>
    <li>Aylin Burgess</li>
    <li>Lukas Roman</li>
    <li>Aden Crawford</li>
    <li>Alexzander Fitzgerald</li>
    <li>Gustavo Dyer</li>
    <li>Allyson Gates</li>
    <li>Tia Munoz</li>
    <li>Ignacio Mcconnell</li>
    <li>Blaze Shelton</li>
    <li>Quentin Hebert</li>
    <li>Kirsten Bowen</li>
    <li>Ryan Nelson</li>
    <li>Giovanny Rowland</li>
    <li>Audrey Costa</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```